# Where in redux-react app would I include my stateful presentational component? In components or containers folder?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Search Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import SearchResults from "../SearchResults";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ value });
    this.props.performSearch(value);
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>The Guardian Search App</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </form>
        <div>
          <SearchResults articles={this.props.articles} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Search.propTypes = {
  performSearch: PropTypes.func,
  articles: PropTypes.array
};

export default Search;
```

**Search Container:**

```
import React from "react";
import Search from "../../components/Search";
import { API_KEY } from "../../../config";

import fetchArticles from "../../api";

class SearchContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articles: []
  };

  performSearch = event => {
    return fetchArticles(event).then(data =>
      this.setState({ articles: data.response.results })
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Search
        performSearch={this.performSearch}
        articles={this.state.articles}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SearchContainer;
```

I am currently trying to get my head around redux so transitioning this into react-redux version. I've got a Search Container whereby I am doing mapStateToProps and will soon write mapDispatchToProps as well. But if my Search component also includes state, do I then do another Search Container to then map its state to props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state required in your `Search` component is directly linked and required by the `input` element that you have rendered as a child. Therefore, the `value` state in the `Search` component should stay within the component and not be associated with Redux.

There is no "correct" way of doing this, mainly preference and design pattern. Since you have state in the `Search` component that you don't want to be associated with Redux, I would hook the `SearchContainer` component into your Redux store for providing the array of article objects which can then be passed to the base `Search` component as a prop and leave that component entirely unaware that Redux even exists.